# R: Character into Date Format, Input like YYYYMMDD

Tags: r

I want to transform my character line into a Date Format to plot my Data. I Tried:

```
a`s.Date(IBM_REK$V1,"%YYYY%MM%DD", optional =FALSE)
```

I get only Na's.

The Data is imported from a text file and Stored in a data-frame. The first line is the date (V1):

```
$ V1: chr  "19260130" "19260227" "19260331" "19260430"
```

I tried other codes like `strp.time()`, but no code works out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strptime` will do the job here. First of all, use `?strptime` to see what kinds of **format** you want to use.

Let's say you have a list of dates:

```
dates = c("19260130", "19260227", "19260331", "19260430")
```

where format seems to be YYYYMMDD.

Using `strptime`:

```
strptime(dates[1], "%Y%m%d")
[1] "1926-01-03"
```

where %Y is 4 digit year, %m is decimal number of months, %d is day.

Comment: @Kindou, Glad it worked :) Please consider marking it as an answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try with below date format.

```
as.Date(IBM_REK$V1,"%Y%m%d", optional =FALSE)
```